# Auto scheduling

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make an auto scheduling program with an excel.

For example, each number is certain job assigned to the person given day.

```
       1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5
Tom     1   2   2   ?
Justin  2   3   1   ?
Mary    3       3   ?
Sam         1       ?

Check   O   O   X   ?   ## check is like =if(b2=c2,"O","X")
```

The things I want to make sure is every person is given a different job from yesterday.

My idea

```
while 
    randomly distribute jobs for 1/5
wend CheckCell = "O"
```

But I found that checking cell in the vba script doesn't work - the cell is not updated in each while loop.

Could you give me a little pointer for these kinds of program? Because I am new to vbaScript, any kinds of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try adding *ActiveSheet.Calculate* inside your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA, I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this will check the values from the penultimate column against values from last column and if they match it will write "O" to under the last column, else it will write "X":

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

counter = 0 'set counter

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through penultimate column and add values to array
    If ws.Cells(i, LastCol - 1).Value <> "" Then
    Values = Values & ws.Cells(i, LastCol - 1) & ","
    End If
Next i

Values = Left(Values, Len(Values) - 1)
Values = Split(Values, ",") 'split values into array

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through last column and add values to array
    If ws.Cells(i, LastCol).Value <> "" Then
    ValuesCheck = ValuesCheck & ws.Cells(i, LastCol) & ","
    End If
Next i
ValuesCheck = Left(ValuesCheck, Len(ValuesCheck) - 1)
ValuesCheck = Split(ValuesCheck, ",")

For y = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values) 'loop through both arrays to find all values match
    For x = LBound(ValuesCheck) To UBound(ValuesCheck)
        If Values(y) = ValuesCheck(x) Then counter = counter + 1
    Next x

Next y
If counter = UBound(Values) + 1 Then 'if values match
    ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol).Value = "O"
Else 'else write X
    ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol).Value = "X"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify are you looking to implement the random number in the vba or the check.

To do the check the best way would be to set the area as a range and then check each using the cells(r,c) code, like below

```
Sub checker()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

Set rng = Selection
For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If rng.Cells(r, c) = rng.Cells(r, c + 1) Then
            rng.Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next c
Next r


End Sub
```

this macro with check the text you have selected for the issue and change the cell red if it matches the value to the right.
To make it work for you change set rng = selection to your range and change the rng.Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) to the action you want

Answer (score 0):

A sligthly different approach than the other answers.
Add this function:

```
Function PickJob(AvailableJobs As String, AvoidJob As String)
    Dim MaxTries As Integer
    Dim RandomJob As String
    Dim Jobs() As String
    Jobs = Split(AvailableJobs, ",")

    MaxTries = 100
    Do
        MaxTries = MaxTries - 1
        If MaxTries = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could find fitting job"
            End
        End If
        RandomJob = Jobs(Int((1 + UBound(Jobs)) * Rnd()))
    Loop Until RandomJob <> AvoidJob
    PickJob = RandomJob
End Function
```

And put this formula in your sheet

```
=PickJob("1,2,3",D2)
```

where D2 points to is the previous job